"Isomorphism theorem" for Lie groups.
I came across this question: link. There it is established that if $G$ be a Lie group and let $F:G \to H$ a surjective Lie group homomorphim such that  $\Gamma=\ker F$ is a discrete subgroup, then the orbit space $G/\Gamma$ is diffeomorphic to $H$. The proof in the question starts like this:
Let $\pi:G \to G/\Gamma$ be the quotient map. Define $\tilde{F}: G/\Gamma \to H$ by $\tilde{F}(\Gamma x) = F(x)$. This is a well defined bijection which is also a homeomorphism.
I see that $\tilde{F}$ is a continuous bijection, but why is it a homeomorphism? I've never studied Lie groups and their properties so could someone quickly explain why this follows? (and would it also hold if $G,H$ were only topological groups?)

You should read not just the question but also the answer.

I'm sorry if I'm overlooking something obvious but the answer just starts with "you proved that this is a homeomorphism..." but doesn't address how this was proved.

You have to read more carefully: it uses the inverse mapping theorem to prove a diffeomorphism.

But there is also a general result about completely metrizable sigma-compact topological groups: every bijective continuous homomorphism is a homeomorphism.

See my answer here.
